# WIX — Add files to both GAC and INSTALLFOLDER without changing the name

Tags: wix

Despite the different Ids and GUIDs the following code refused to compile because the following components have the same name. Setting the Name attribute does the trick, but I don't want libraries to have different names in GAC and install folder.

So far I have circumvented the issue by creating a CustomAction that renames one of the components on install, but this clearly isn't optimal. Is there an out of the box solution?

```
<ComponentGroup Id="HistoryGroup" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
     <Component Id="History" Guid="*">
            <File Source="$(var.ProjectName.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>
     </Component>
     <Component Id="HistoryGAC" Guid="*">
            <File Source="$(var.ProjectName.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net"/>
     </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give both file elements explicit unique Id attributes.  For the one going to the GAC install it to another dummy folder that already exists. (Don't worry it won't get installed there, it'll go to the GAC.)

Comment: I completely missed the fact that you could apply Ids to Files and not just Components and that's what caused the duplicate issue the compiler was pointing towards.

Comment: Many of the WiX elements have an Id attribute which maps to the primary key of a Windows Installer table.  WiX tries to simplify authoring and allow you to ommit the attribute and one will be generated dynamically at build time.  I suppose a feature request could be put in for WiX to see that one is GAC and one isn't and generate unique Ids.  Personally I author everything explicitly.